# Link "equivalent" nodes using Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I confess being new to Cypher. 
I'm trying to graph Media newspapers in France and the US (Media as a Node) with their PoliticalOrientation (other node). The Relationship [:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS] exists and all is fine.
    MATCH p=(m:Media)-[r:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]->(o:PoliticalOrientation)
Now, since those PoliticalOrientations have different names but some are EQUIVALENT between France and the US, like "Left" in France and "Democrats US" in the US, I'd like to create this relationship [:EQUIVALENT] and show the relationships on the graph.
I'm stuck here, which does not show those [:EQUIVALENT] links:

```
// custom relations in politics
CREATE (t:PoliticalOrientation { name:'Democrat US' })-[z:EQUIVALENT]->(u:PoliticalOrientation { name: 'Left' })
with t,z,u
MATCH (m:Media)-[:IS_LISTED_IN_CUSTOM_LISTS]->(p:CustomLists)
Match (m)-[:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]->(r:PoliticalOrientation)
MATCH zz=()-[rr:EQUIVALENT]->()
WHERE p.name CONTAINS "NEWS" AND NOT r.name = "None"
RETURN m,p,r,zz,rr
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This query should return equivalent `PoliticalOrientation` nodes and their `Media` nodes:

```
MATCH (r:PoliticalOrientation)<-[:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]-(m:Media)-[:IS_LISTED_IN_CUSTOM_LISTS]->(p:CustomLists)
WHERE p.name CONTAINS "NEWS" AND r.name <> 'None'
WITH COLLECT(r) AS rs, COLLECT(m) AS ms
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(rs)-1) AS i
WITH ms, rs, rs[i] AS r1, ms[i] AS m1
MATCH (r1)-[:EQUIVALENT]-(r2)
WHERE r2 IN rs
RETURN r1, m1, r2, [j IN RANGE(0, SIZE(rs)-1) WHERE rs[j] = r2 | ms[j]][0] AS m2
```

Comment: Thanks Cybersam. unfortunately it returns (no changes, no records). Sorry.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data (via some `CREATE` clauses)?

Comment: CREATE p =(Media { name:'NewspaperFR1' })-[:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]->(PoliticalOrientation { name: 'Left' })
CREATE p =(Media { name:'NewspaperFR2' })-[:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]->(PoliticalOrientation { name: 'Left' })
CREATE p =(Media { name:'NewspaperFR3’ })-[:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]->(PoliticalOrientation { name: ‘Right’ })
CREATE p =(Media { name:'NewspaperUS1' })-[:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]->(PoliticalOrientation { name: ‘Center’ })
CREATE p =(Media { name:'NewspaperUS2’ })-[:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]->(PoliticalOrientation { name: ‘Democrats US’})

Comment: I know how to graph Media and PoliticalOrientation. What can't do is in this graph (media -> PoliticalOrientation) How to also view this CREATE (t:PoliticalOrientation { name:'Democrat US' })-[z:EQUIVALENT]->(u:PoliticalOrientation { name: 'Left' })

Comment: Your CREATE statements are creating a lot of duplicate nodes. Also, since the created data is missing a lot of nodes and relationships, there is naturally no way that my query would return anything. You seem to have a lot of basic questions. I would suggest taking the time to learn the Cypher language. [This page on Cypher](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/) is a good place to start.